# How does one ask for a boon?

Tags: shiva, meditation, boon, tapasya

What mantra/strota should I chant to ask for a boon from God? Or, how do I do tapasya for a boon?

Comment: Ask the boon with devotion. You'll definitely get it. He is very compassionate and cannot see us (his children) suffering.

Comment: I want crime and injustice(adharma) to end from the world.

Comment: Then ask him. Let's see, if everything goes in favour, maybe you could change the world.  I had a question in my mind and now after your reply, the question again popped up. I think I'm going to ask that in this site.

Comment: Inform me if you get the answer to your question.What was your question?

Comment: I have asked it today itself :)

Comment: Try peepal tree worship in Brahm muhurat by giving water to root of peepal tree,saying wish and Circling root 7 times in clockwise direction. Since I had tried in 2017, it helps.  But don't wish bad for others or yourself.